# Put labels on the diagonal of a matrix in a Matlab Plot

Tags: image, matlab, plot, axis-labels, diagonal

In Matlab, suppose you `imagesc` a square matrix. Is there a way to plot the `Xticklabels` on the diagonal?

Comment: I don't think there's an automated tool for that, but you can use the [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) command to achieve the same effect.

Comment: thanks a lot EitanT! It's a good hint!

Comment: No problem. If you're running into trouble, let me know -- I'll post an answer that shows how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a diagonal square matrix of size, n=4:

```
figure; imagesc( diag( ones(1, 4) )  );
```

Employ the `text()` command inside a loop to put the tick labels as strings:

```
for i = 1:n 
    text( i, i, num2str(i)); 
end
```

See below:

[image]

A good relevant reference: to [Add labels on top of Histogram bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501432/how-can-i-add-labels-of-values-to-the-top-of-my-matlab-plot)